# Git - Cloning Vue.js project and run

Tags: vue.js, npm, npm-install

I have cloned a project from a Git Repo into my Mac, It only has project files not the node modules.

In GIT : Readme.md says run npm install to setup the project.
When I run the npm install I get below error list, how do I get through it?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @vue/eslint-config-standard@6.1.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint-plugin-vue@8.7.1
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-vue
npm ERR!   dev eslint-plugin-vue@"^8.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint-plugin-vue@"^7.0.0" from @vue/eslint-config-standard@6.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/eslint-config-standard
npm ERR!   dev @vue/eslint-config-standard@"^6.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint-plugin-vue@7.20.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-vue
npm ERR!   peer eslint-plugin-vue@"^7.0.0" from @vue/eslint-config-standard@6.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/eslint-config-standard
npm ERR!     dev @vue/eslint-config-standard@"^6.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/dev/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dev/.npm/_logs/2022-06-23T23_17_06_125Z-debug-0.log
```

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors).

Comment: Note that the fact that you've cloned a project via Git does not mean you have a Git issue. What you have here is an npm dependency issue.

Comment: @phd Thanks, I have edited it witht he error im getting.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to get rid of the problem was removing the:

> "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",

line in the package.json file.
from the "devDependencies" section.

Then I did an

> npm install

to download all the dependencies. And after that I downloaded the eslint Vue plugin seperatly with the Vue CLI.

> vue add eslint

I don't know if this is **the** solution to the problem. I just wanted to help.

Answer (score 0):

This bug seems current, to reproduce it :

```
vue create hello-world
Vue CLI v5.0.8
...
npm install
```

and if you do : `rm -rf node_modules` then `npm install` you get error :

```
npm ERR! While resolving: @vue/eslint-config-standard@6.1.0
```

And no solution till now

thank you

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32904382)